# Improve sbt doc generation

Tags: scala, documentation-generation, lift, sbt

When I run `sbt doc`, it results in a nice but nonetheless pretty basic documentation. Is it possible to

a) include the source files for the class definition and

b) inherit the docstrings for inherited members?

What do I need to add to my project definition?

(It’s a Lift project, so most important would be to have the inherited Lift docstrings present.)

Answer (score 5):

a) [Scala X-Ray](http://github.com/harrah/browse) (sxr) will give you source code as documentation. It's a compiler plugin and it is most excellent. That link includes a link to the sxr+sbt setup.

b) I am sorry. I can't help with this one.

Comment: Nice. Now if only scaladoc would be able to link to the sxr source.

Comment: The scaladoc ant target has the `docsourceurl` attribute. See http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_final/build.xml#L1379 It should be possible to achieve this. I also found this here http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/BuildConfiguration#Document_Options